# jQuery Tools Overlay - Two buttons with different close conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

I have the following jQuery Tools overlay:

```
<div id='editDescriptiontOverlay' class='overlay'>
  <input type='text' class='description'/>
  <button class='save'>Save</button>
  <button class='close'>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**Background info**: The HTML for this overlay is static. I have a list of items each having their own *Edit* link. When a given *Edit* link is clicked, the overlay is generated by calling: `$('a[rel=#editDescriptionOverlay]').overlay( { ... } );` and the input is populated with the respective text.

The *Save* button needs to validate the text in the input element and **close** the overlay if and only if the validation is successful. Otherwise, the overlay must remain open. The *Cancel* button simply closes the overlay without validation.

The validation logic has been independently verified to work.

I've tried setting the `onBeforeClose` event during overlay generation as a means of validation.  Taking this approach, both the *Save* and *Cancel* buttons needed the same class `.close`. Unfortunately, the condition applies to all `.close` elements in the overlay so even the *Cancel* button was validating.

I've also tried binding a click event to the *Save* button immediately after generating the overlay, like so:

```
$('.save', $('#editDescriptionOverlay'))
  .unbind('click')
  .bind('click', function() {
    if (validateText) {
      console.log("Validation passed.");
      $('a[rel=#editDescriptionOverlay]').overlay().close();
    }
    else {
      console.log("Validation failed.");
    }
  });
```

The console.log's confirm that the validation is working, but the overlay doesn't close.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jquery widgets, public methods should be called as follows:

$('a[rel=#editDescriptionOverlay]').overlay("close");

wherein close is the method name that you wish to call.

If a method accepts parameters, then, these should be added as parameters right after the method name.

**Updated:**

I am sorry. I just had time to check what jQuery Overlay Tools is and I am mistaken. This is not similar to any jQuery widget, hence, my comment above will also not work for this case. I tried your code above and it worked. The overlay was closed. But, when I tried it with multiple `<a rel="#editDescriptionOverlay">`, which I think is what you did. It did not work. My suggestion would be to use just one `<a rel="#editDescriptionOverlay">` and use a dummy anchor element for the Edit link, which when clicked would trigger a click to `<a rel="#editDescriptionOverlay">`. You can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).bind("ready", function(e){
        $("a[rel]").overlay();
        $('.save', $('#editDescriptionOverlay')).unbind("click").bind("click", function(){
            if (validationValue){
                $("a[rel=#editDescriptionOverlay]").overlay().close();
            }
        });
    });

    function clickThis(){
        $("a[rel=#editDescriptionOverlay]").trigger('click'); 
        return false;
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="return clickThis();">Edit1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return clickThis();">Edit2</a>

<a rel="#editDescriptionOverlay">Dummy</a>

<div id='editDescriptionOverlay' class='overlay'>
  <input type='text' class='description'/>
  <button class='save'>Save</button>
  <button class='close'>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the above-statement calling a method with parameters? Also, how would this be linked to the button click?

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer binding an event to the save button (the second one you mentioned). Actually your code looks fine, except that you probably don't need to bind the event to `$('#editDescriptionOverlay')` and you have typo in your html markup above (`<div id='editDescriptiontOverlay'` should be `<div id='editDescriptionOverlay'`).

See [here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/sM58e/3/).